# Using Apache as a https reverse proxy to varnish

Tags: apache-2.4, varnish, debian-jessie

In *debian jessie* I'm trying to serve https with a varnish reverse proxy, and I found the following solution: http://davidbu.ch/mann/blog/2015-03-20/varnish-and-https-apache.html : apache manages ssl stuff on port 443, then passes to varnish on port 80, which passes to apache at port 8080.

However, requesting `https://myserver.com/index.html` I get in the browser:

```
403 Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

Apache's error.log says:

```
[authz_core:error] [pid 12662] [client 151.16.175.15:38240] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: proxy:http://127.0.0.1:80/index.html
```

What am I missing?

My vhost definition

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin mymail@gmail.com
    ServerName myserver.com

    DocumentRoot /home/paolo/weewx
    <Directory /home/paolo/weewx/>
        DirectoryIndex index.html
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    # ErrorDocument 404 /index.html

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin mymail@gmail.com
    ServerName myserver.com

    DocumentRoot /home/paolo/weewx/
    <Directory /home/paolo/weewx/>
        DirectoryIndex index.html
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    # ErrorDocument 404 /index.html

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:80/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:80/
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/qumran2/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/qumran2/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>


</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't set a document root in a Virtual Host entry that will only be a used to proxy requests. Especially when you include an `AllowOverride All` directive tehre and `.htaccess` files can come into play.

For debugging it may also help to define separate log files for each Virtual Host entry as well.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin mymail@gmail.com
    ServerName example.com
    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/example.com-ssl-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/example.com-ssl-access.log combined
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:80/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:80/
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/qumran2/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/qumran2/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

And you can debug by requesting the resource directly from port 8080 with for instance `curl --verbose --header 'Host: example.com' 'http://localhost:8080/index.html'` to see if that VirtualHost is the problem.

If it is not; then try varnish on port 80, to see if the problem is in Varnish. `curl --verbose --header 'Host: example.com' 'http://localhost:80/index.html`

Comment: unfortunatly the output of those `curl` commands get a content different from the one served to browsers. Is it possible that curl command are managed differently than page serving?

Comment: That depends on your complete setup.

Comment: I uninstalled munin, and everything is well now, perhaps something was conflicting.